# Angular 2 (TypeScript) data modal generator from json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a lot of json objects of different types. I want to bulk generate TypeScript modals using those json. I want some automated mechanism or some service or lib to generate data modals from my json.

For example if I have

```
{
 "name": "John"
}
```

Library should extract TypeScript modal like

```
export class User {
  name: string;
}
```

Any HELP

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Also, I think you mean models, not modals.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this online supporter to generate a ts from a json, Paste a JSON string into the textarea and hit the button to generate the **`TypeScript interfaces`**. 
You can place this in a typescript definition file, like 'someDefinition.d.ts' for example, and use that in your project.

**[`json2ts`](http://json2ts.com/)**

Comment: Can you please show example how we can use this in our project? because it has given this formate "let c = require('json2ts)"
but i want to import it in typscript file
like import...